# Show that a surface is minimal - scherk

Tags: differential-geometry

Have to show that first scherk surface is minimal :

We have
$f(x,y)=(x,y,\ln(\cos x/\cos y))$

I am trying to show that using $H=1/2(k+k')=0$ (this is the definition given in the course) k and k' the principal curvatures but I don't get 0.

Calculating the second fundamental form :

$f_x=(1,0,-\tan x)$

$f_{xx}=(0,0,-\sec^2 x)$

$f_y=(0,1,\tan y)$

$f_{yy}=(0,0,\sec^2 y)$

$f_{xy}=(0,0,0)$

Normal vector

$n=f_{xx}\times f_y / ||f_{xx}\times f_y||$

$n=(\tan x,-\tan y,0)/a$

I take $a= ||f_{xx}\times f_y|| = (\tan^2 x+\tan^2 y+1)^{1/2}$

So the coefficients of second fundamental form are

$l=f_{xx}.n= -\sec^2 x/a$

$m=0$

$n= \sec^2 y/a$

So the matrix

I find $k=\sec^2 x/a$ and $k'=\sec^2 y/a$ 
So $H$ is different from $0$ ?
I don't know where I messed up
Thanks !

Comment: You need a different letter for the normal vector, to distinguish it from $n$. Also you mean to have $f_x\times f_y$. You also have a typo in the calculation of the unit normal. But your mistake is calculating from just the second fundamental form ($\ell, m, n$). You need the first fundamental form, as well, and then the eigenvalues of the product of the inverse of that matrix and the matrix of the second fundamental form.

Comment: If I understand, the calculations must be done using the shape operator ? Edit : Thanks for pointing my mistake, I just realised that I was not understanding the notion of gauss and principal curvatures the right way !